# Cytoscape; Directed network betweenness & closeness centrality

Tags: directed-graph, cytoscape, network-analysis

I have a directed network in cytoscape. The network shows stakeholders (nodes) who share information  (edges) with other stakeholders (edges). The information sharing is directed, so a stakeholder can share and/or receive information. I want to calculate betweenness centrality and closeness centrality however my values for betweenness centrality are >1 when I use the analyse network tool specifying it as a directed network. All literature I have found so far state that the value should between 0-1.
When I analyse the network as un-directed, all values for betweenness and closeness centrality change and are between 0-1.

Should I use the undirected values? Or is there a way to get the values for a directed network?

I tried analysing it as directed and undirected.

Answer (score 0):

We can reproduce the behavior of generating >1 values of betweenness on directed networks.  We are not convinced that this is incorrect, but will open a bug report to dig into the implementation to confirm.

The code is open source: https://github.com/cytoscape/network-analyzer